# Multiple UICollectionViews in ViewController | Would not call one CollectionViews Delegate methods

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, storyboard, swift4

SO I have two `UICollectionViews` in my `UIViewController` in Storyboard and both are linked with delegate and datasource to my ViewController. All the associated `UICollectionView` delegate methods are implemented and checks for the `UICollectionViews` are implemented. But it's so frustrating that one `UICollectionView` is getting catered while the other one is getting completely ignored. I have scratched my head in all the available aspects but it is kind of putting me further towards the edge, please help.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == self.variantsCollectionView {
//            let count = (item?.variant_groups?.count)!
            return 1
        } else {
            return 2//(item?.extra_groups?.count)!
        }
    }
```

and

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

        if collectionView == self.variantsCollectionView {
            //IT DOESNT EVEN COME HERE AT ALL
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell_variant", for: indexPath)
            return cell

        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            //HERE IT COMES ALWAYS FOR THE NUMBER OF CELLS

            return cell
        }

    }
```

Whereas the UICollectionViews are connected like this:
[image]

and:
[image]

Please please help. Thank you so much

Comment: Remove the delegate connection for the working collection view and check if data source methods are executed for the `variantsCollectionView` at all.

Comment: If they do, then `if collectionView == self.variantsCollectionView {` not working. In that case, check if IBOutlet for `variantsCollectionView` is connected properly.

Comment: @Evgeniy no they are not getting called for the working collection now neither are they working for the other one

Comment: Check in viewDidLoad() that collection's dataSource is not nil.

Comment: @Evgeniy if all the delegate and datasource connections are connected, none is nil. 
Optional(<Project.ProductExtrasVC: 0x7fb540c111d0>)
Optional(<Project.ProductExtrasVC: 0x7fb540c111d0>)
Optional(<Project.ProductExtrasVC: 0x7fb540c111d0>)
Optional(<Project.ProductExtrasVC: 0x7fb540c111d0>)

Comment: Then check the cellSizeForItem, it must be 0,0 somehow.

Comment: @Evgeniy Your answer basically led me to the actual answer... basically CollectionView has a specific height whereas VariantCollectionView didnt, and both were in a stackView. When first was created in view it took up the entire size where as the other one kind of actually disappeared. Hence the issue. Kudos to you for making me get to this. And if you could answer this to my question, i would accept it and get you some reputation :D

Comment: Glad to help ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via comments the TS found solution by following these steps:

1. Ensure both collection views have non-nil data sources (and delegates).
2. Check that data source methods are executed for both collection view.
3. Check that both collection views' cells have valid size.

Finally the problem was found after checking the heights of each collection view inside stack view.

> basically CollectionView has a specific height whereas
>   VariantCollectionView didnt, and both were in a stackView. When first
>   was created in view it took up the entire size where as the other one
>   kind of actually disappeared. Hence the issue.